# Работа со списком

Tags: c#, list, список

Строго не судите я только учусь, есть класс

```
public class ListUrlProduct
{

    private List<string> get_url_category = new List<string>();

    //ЗАПИСЫВАЕМ В СПИСОК
    public void Write(string s)
    {
        get_url_category.Add(s);
    }

    //ВЫВОДИМ ЭЛЕМЕНТ ПО ИНДЕКСУ
    public string ReadElement(int i)
    {
        return get_url_category.ElementAt(i);
    }
}
```

Заполняю `get_url_category`, как обратится к содержимому `get_url_category` в другом классе?

Comment: Что то я впервые вижу:

   что-то
   {
      ...
   }

Вроде как вот так и красивей, и корректней(?):

   что-то {
      ...
    }

Comment: @danpetruk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Styles

Я лично предпочитаю стиль. который в статье назван "Allman style".

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если ваш список приватный, то прямо к нему обратиться нельзя.

Но это и хорошо, другим классам не должно быть дело до ваших внутренних данных. Пусть пользуются функцией `ReadElement`.

Я бы ещё предоставил публичную функцию `GetNumberOfElements`. Или вместо `ReadElement` дал бы

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadAllElements() { return get_url_category.AsReadOnly(); }
```

Comment: namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ListUrlProduct ListUrlProduct = new ListUrlProduct();
ListUrlProduct.Write("Текст");
MessageBox.Show(ListUrlProduct.ReadElement(0));}

public class ListUrlProduct
{
     private List<string> get_url_category = new List<string>();

        public void Write(string s)
        {
            get_url_category.Add(s);
        }

        public string ReadElement(int i)
        {
            return get_url_category.ElementAt(i);
}
}
}
вот так работает

Comment: а вот так нет, это ProductInfo.cs
namespace test
{
    class ProductInfo
    {
  public void GetProductInfo()
        {
   ListUrlProduct ListUrlProduct = new ListUrlProduct();
   MessageBox.Show(ListUrlProduct.ReadElement(0));
  }
 }
}

Comment: В первом случае в список добавляется элемент перед обращением, а втором нет.

Comment: вызываю так:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductInfo ProductInfo = new ProductInfo();
            ProductInfo.GetProductInfo();
        }

Comment: @while! Вы новый объект `ListUrlProduct` создаете в `GetProductInfo()`! Какой еще элемент добавляется при загрузке формы? 
Это же не процедурное программирование... У Вас чуть "хромает" понимание ООП. Без обид.

Comment: Ну конечно. В `GetProductInfo()` вы создаете абсолютно новый объект, который никак не является "тем, что в `Form1_Load`". И еще, никогда не называйте экземпляр объектом именем его же типа, т.е. `ListUrlProduct ListUrlProduct` - это некорректно, используйте `ListUrlProduct lup`.

Comment: спасибо всем, разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Ну это же базовые принципы ООП!

```
ListUrlProduct lu = new ListUrlProduct();
lu.Write("zzzz");
Console.Write(lu.ReadElement(0));
```

Comment: не работает, в общем у меня Form1.cs и ProductInfo.cs,
если я вызываю в Form1.cs Console.Write(lu.ReadElement(0)); то все прекрасно работает, а если эту строчку кода использовать в ProductInfo.cs то выдает
"Дополнительные сведения: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции."

Comment: @while Вы уж так бы и самого начала. "Там где не работает", т.е. "во время" ProductInfo.cs у вас коллекция пустая стало быть.

Comment: Ну если пустая, то стало быть элемента с индексом 0 тоже не существует. И компилятор выдает вполне справедливый вердикт - "Индекс за пределами диапазона..".

Comment: а если я вызову тоже самое в Form1.cs то все прекрасно работает

Comment: ListUrlProduct ListUrlProduct = new ListUrlProduct();
ListUrlProduct.Write("текст");
Console.Write(ListUrlProduct .ReadElement(0));
работает в Form1.cs

Comment: @while *.cs - это всего лишь имена файлов. В каждом из этих файлов я могу расположить один или более классов с разными доступами и функционалом и пр. Мне кажется, что Вы не до конца понимаете принципы ООП - здесь надо копать, потому что не "из Form1.cs" работает и или не работает, а надо смотреть что в каких классах.

Comment: @while Впрочем, пойдем другим путём: код ProductInfo.cs в студию.